# Access 2010: Database cannot be opened because the VBA project cannot be read

Tags: windows-8, vba, microsoft-access-2010

I used a simple software made with access on windows 8 s.o. with accde extension

After formatted pc and installed windows 7, I can't run software because "Access 2010: Database cannot be opened because the VBA project cannot be read"

I'm trying to install all versione of access 2010, RTM, sp1, sp2 but always same problem...

How I can resolve this?